# Arduino Mega 2560 LED is dim when powered from digital output

Tags: led

My circuit is a simple one, I am using an arduino atmega 2560.
One 5mm red LED connected in series with a 150 ohm resistor.
If I didn't make some kind of goof, a red LED has a voltage drop of 2 volts and operates at 20 ma.
So my calculations were, 5-2=3volts.
3V/150=20 mA. So I put a 150 ohm resistor.
My code to control it is the following:

```
int red = 48;

void setup() {
pinMode(OUTPUT,red);    
}

void loop() {    
digitalWrite(red,HIGH);
}
```

When I run the code the red LED is dimly lit, when connected to the 5V on the board it lights brightly.
When I measured the voltage between pin48 and ground I got 1.7 volts.
When connected directly to the 5V and GND the voltage between them is 4.95V.
Measuring a pin with nothing connected set at HIGH results in a 4.99V reading.
Is my board malfunctioning or have I missed something?

Comment: It's `pinMode(red, OUTPUT)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pinMode()` arguments are backwards. As it is the LED is powered through the input pullup resistor, which is about 20-50kohm.

Comment: You sir deserve a pizza, thank you so much!
I noticed it now, what a dumb mistake :D
Well I fixed it now and it works.
Cheers again for the help.